# Find a Decorator of a particular type when using the Decorator Pattern?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, reflection, decorator

I'm building an app that needs to use multiple types of similar sensors. Since the sensors could also have different behaviours, or combinations of behaviours, I decided to use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

In short, I have a hierarchy that looks like this:

[image]

So any of the concrete `ISensorDecorator` classes can decorate (wrap) any of the concrete `IMeasureSensor` classes, but since a concrete  `ISensorDecorator` also is a concrete `IMeasureSensor`, they can wrap each other. So for example

```
IMeasureSensor sensor = new FilteredSensorDecorator(
    new CalibratedSensorDecorator(
        new AccelerometerSensor()
    )
);
```

is a valid statement that declares a filtered and calibrated accelerometer sensor.

Now let's say I have a method called `setCalibration()` in `CalibratedSensorDecorator`. Obviously I can't call

```
sensor.setCalibration();
```

because `IMeasureSensor` doesn't have a `setCalibration()` method. And trying to use

```
((CalibratedSensorDecorator)sensor).setCalibration()
```

won't work either, since `sensor` is a `FilteredSensorDecorator`.

How can I get to the `CalibratedSensorDecorator` in this particular case, and more generally to any specific decorator in any "chain" of decorators? I don't want to store them as separate variables, I want to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer by Sagar discusses some (valid) reasons for considering using another approach than the decorator pattern, I came up with a working solution for the actual problem of finding the correct decorator.

```
/**
 * Walks the decorator hierarchy recursively from the outside in (excluding the final
 * IMeasureSensor which is not a ISensorDecorator), and returns the decorator of the given class.
 * If none can be found, null is returned.
 */
IMeasureSensor findDecorator(IMeasureSensor sensor, Class decoratorClass){
    if( ISensorDecorator.class.isAssignableFrom(sensor.getClass()) ){
        return (sensor.getClass() == decoratorClass) 
            ? sensor 
            : findDecorator(((ISensorDecorator) sensor).getDecoratee(), decoratorClass);
    } 
    else
        return null;
}
```

The method `ISensorDecorator.getDecoratee()` simply returns the "decoratee", i.e. the `IMeasureSensor` that the decorator decorates.

```
public IMeasureSensor getDecoratee(){
    return mMeasureSensor;
}
```

You can then use `findDecorator()` to find a (the outermost) decorator of a given type like this:

```
IMeasureSensor sensor;

...

CalibratedSensorDecorator s = (CalibratedSensorDecorator) findDecorator(sensor, CalibratedSensorDecorator.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since its a design question, there won't be any right answer, you need to make choice which could be good or not that good.

You shouldn't add a method for particular class since it will violate the `Liskov substitution principle`

> Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.

You can initialize the `calibration` in constructor `CalibratedSensorDecorator` and use it while executing your required function.

If that doesn't meet your requirement, then may be `CalibratedSensorDecorator` doesn't belong in your sensor hierarchy. Consider separating it and use Strategy pattern to decide which one to use.

### Edit 1:

> what I understand it doesn't say that you shouldn't add methods to subtypes?

Yes, you are right. It doesn't prohibit from adding methods but if the methods are changing the state of an Object, then it should be re-considered. All these patterns are just the guidelines which can be tweaked as per our needs.

**To explain my rationale:**

Imagine you have create the `setCalibration()` on `CalibratedSensorDecorator`. You have following way to expose `CalibratedSensorDecorator` to either internal developer or to external developer. You have created a Factory which just returns `IMeasureSensor` as follows:

```
public IMeasureSensor getCalibratedSensor(){
    ...
}
```

Now the user of your API simply gets this and is happy that his/her current code is working. But realizes that he/she missed to `setCalibration()` which was found after hours of debugging. Moreover he/she has to write the type checking and type casting code to make use of this feature, which might not be great for clean code.

You should try to keep your classes as immutable as possible so that the debugging and maintenance are at ease. There is no harm in recreating the object since the older will be garbage collected.

Again its just my suggestion, its your decision to carefully consider what's best for your use-case. You can still go ahead with your new approach to create the method if its mandatory and ensure proper documentation has been made to make user understand the usage.

Comment: I'm no expert in the Liskov substitution principle, but from what I understand it doesn't say that you shouldn't add methods to subtypes? If that were the case, wouldn't inheritance be of very limited use? I'm actually doing exactly what you propose, taking a `calibration` parameter in the constructor. But I would like to be able to change the calibration and other parameters without having to recreate new objects just for the sake of changing a variable...

Comment: Thanks, I see your point.If I were to use the strategy pattern instead, how would I "chain" together an arbitrary number of strategies though?

Comment: Well the strategy could be to categorize your sensors in two: one which doesn't need the `calibration` and another which needs calibration. Let's say `IMeasureSensor ` is one without `calibration` and `IMeasureSensorWithCalibration` another one and let user of your API decide which one he/she prefers. You can also extend `IMeasureSensor ` in `IMeasureSensorWithCalibration` so indicate interface segregation.